# Is it possible to make single parameterized cursor for the below 3 select statements

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, parameterized, database-cursor

```sql
-- statement 1
select * from table_1 where id = in_id;
-- statement 2
select * from table_1 where id = in_id 
and productt_type = in_product_type
and item is not null;
-- statement 3
select * from table_1 where id = in_id 
and productt_type = in_product_type
AND NVL(DOC_CATEGORY,'N') IN ('PS')
and item is not null;
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, Oracle database 11g release 2.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you're asking, see if this helps:

```
select *
from table_1
where (id = in_id or in_id is null)
  and (productt_type = in_product_type or in_product_type is null)
  and nvl(doc_category, 'N') = 'PS'
  and item is not null
```

---

To convert it to a parametrized cursor:

```
SQL> desc table_1
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- --------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 PRODUCTT_TYPE                                      VARCHAR2(20)
 DOC_CATEGORY                                       VARCHAR2(2)
 ITEM                                               NUMBER

SQL> declare
  2    cursor c1 (in_id           number,
  3               in_product_type varchar2
  4              )
  5    is
  6    select *
  7      from table_1 t
  8      where (t.id = in_id or in_id is null)
  9        and (   t.productt_type = in_product_type
 10             or in_product_type is null)
 11        and nvl(t.doc_category, 'N') = 'PS'
 12        and t.item is not null;
 13    c1r c1%rowtype;
 14  begin
 15    open c1(1, 'A');
 16    fetch c1 into c1r;
 17    close c1;
 18  end;
 19  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: No, I want make a single cursor with provided where conditions, your answer is correct in select statement.

Comment: If query is OK, then it isn't difficult to *convert* it to a parametrized cursor; you could have done it yourself. If you didn't, I did it for you, edited the answer and posted some more code. Have a look, please.